# Ringtone shortened with lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, ringtone

Having issue since update to Lollipop on Samsung Galaxy S5. 
When phone rings, sound comes on for 1 second, off for 3, one for 1, off for 3. This happens with Zedge and system ringtones. 
I have changed ringtone to one from the system. Checked settings til I'm almost blue in the face. Thought it might have something to do with motions, but no.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i searched over and over for a solution and finally found it this morning, remembered you had the same problem and had to post this for you...
follow these steps:

1. go to settings...
2. go to accessibility
3. go to answering/ending calls
4. uncheck the "using voice commands" box

and that's it...test it to be sure but it worked for me... i hope it works for you as well...

let me know if it worked... i need to know it worked for you too...